# PagerSlidingTabStrip: ViewPager tabs resize

Tags: android-fragments, android-pageradapter, android-sliding

How to show the tabs in the ViewPager to the one screen? I am using android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.

When i used this

these tabs are shown in one scrren.

**String[] tabs = {"A","B","C","D"};**

when i used this

```
<b> String[] tabs = {"My School", "My Home","Search & Find", "Books & Books"};</b>
```

these tabs are shown with swaping,not in one screen.

How can i put these tabs in one screen.
plz help me

Answer (score 3):

Include this to your PagerSlidingTabStrip

```
app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
```

This maybe work.
Sorry for my english, I am from Venezuela! :-)

Comment: Don't forget to define `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` right after `xmlns:android`.